# Best way of solving an algebra problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I understand this might be trivial, but algebra is not one of my strong suits and I would like to know the best/fastest way of solving an algebra problem.
Say I have the equation $3x + (9 - (x ^ 2)) = 7x - (100 - (x ^ 2))$
Right now I would divide make the $x ^ 2$ into $x$ and the $x ^ 2$ into $x$. From there I would get stuck and guess the answer since there aren't any numbers with a GCF, this is where I need someone's help.
I also can't find a good tag, so any help there is useful.

Comment: Check please your equation again.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg what about it, I was using it for an example, not a real problem

Comment: @MorganRodgers then I'll come up with an easier problem, this one came off the top of my head.

Comment: Generally, you add and subtract from both sides until you have zero on one side of the equals sign, and a polynomial on the other.  Then you attempt to factor the polynomial.

Comment: @MorganRodgers this is how I learned to do it, get the simplest version on each side.

Comment: "Algebra problem" is too broad a category. Your example is how to solve a polynomial in one variable. There are no analytic methods for doing this for degree higher than degree 4. Beginning students usually learn methods for degrees 1 and 2, then learn how to solve others by factoring or by various methods of locating rational solutions, etc.

Comment: I have no idea what is going on here. or why there are responses relating to a degree $4$ equation when the version of the question I can currently see is only second degree. So I have voted to close as unclear.

Comment: @MarkBennet: the question has been edited and the 4th degree equation has been replaced by a second degree equation.

Comment: @MorganRodgers: indeed - I did not say the question made much sense. I was just trying to explain why people were talking about 4th degree where none such exists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per your equation: $3x + (9 - (x ^ 2)) = 7x - (100 - (x ^ 2))$

Solving this yields, 
\begin{align}
& 3x + (9 - (x ^ 2)) = 7x - (100 - (x ^ 2)) \\
\implies & 3x + 9 - x^{2} = 7x - 100 + x^{2} \\
\implies & 2 x^{2} + 4x - 109 = 0
\end{align}
Now the solution can be found as: 
\begin{align}
x = \dfrac{-4 \pm \sqrt{16 + 8 \times 109}}{4} = -8.44983,\, 6.44983 
\end{align}

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) for details.

Comment: thanks, that helps a lot for seeing what steps I should take.